# CSS: adjust box width with margins?

Tags: css, width, margin, box

i have a box whose width is variable because it depends of the size of a container. The box has no content so im using margins to define its width relatively but it is not working. This is my code:

```
.box {
  background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #826200;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  margin: -20px 0 7px -7px;
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
}
```

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/3/

Please notice how the red border goes outside of the box without honoring the right margin and if i set the width to auto then the red border wont display at all. Is it possible to solve this using CSS only?

Thank you.

Comment: what are you actually expecting to see?

Comment: The red line covering the top border of the box on the background

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the fiddle and noticed the top red border wasn't showing.

It had a line with the padding: 0 100%;
Removing that line seem to fix your issue.

Is this the final result you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/z5952/

```
.box {
  background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #826200;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box:before {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  content: "";
  margin: -9px 0 7px -7px;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hmm no, please see my fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/6/ the red line is showing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/16/

since you are using `position:absolute` to position the line, you may also use `top`, `right` and `left` to control the position and width as well:

```
.box:before {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  content: "";

  padding: 0 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the red line still goes outside of the box here.

Comment: which box are you referring to? the one with thinker border?

Comment: Yes, the one with the goldne border. But seems like its fixed now, i just replaced padding with width: auto and that did the trick. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Alright, that is great. But I still think adjusting top, right and left seems to be a more sensible/readable solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/17/

Comment: I kinda did that, please look at my final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7rrj/19/ this is what i intended.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found the answer thanks to an idea given to me by Edward. The problem was solved by replacing margins with top, left and right.

```
.box {
  background: url("back.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover  transparent;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #826200;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box:before {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  content: "";
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}
```